# Issue with HTML links in TextView

Tags: java, android

So, I'm curious as to how to make this work... I'm pulling from an API and one of the elements is in HTML. So, I thought it would be cool to make those links clickable. However, some of those links aren't complete as they are tied directly to the site from where I am getting the API data from.

Here's an example of what I have:

```
textSummary.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textSummary.setText(Html.fromHtml(object.getDescription()));
```

Now, if I click on a link that starts with "http://" everything works great. It gives me the option of which browser to open it in. However, if the href looks like this:

```
/inxile-entertainment-inc/3010-3966
```

I obviously get an error because the intent doesn't have a properly formatted Url. All that I should have to add to this is:

```
http://www.giantbomb.com
```

to get the partial href to work.

Is there a way of doing this with the end result being device launching the default browser (or a browser outside of my app in general)?

Thanks!

Edit: Here is some more information.

Here's the TextView in question. Essentially, this is coming from a fragment that populates this based on the data brought in from the API.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/detail_summary"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="3dp"
    android:paddingEnd="3dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Error:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/inxile-entertainment-inc/3010-3966 (has extras) }
```

This link will give me the option to choose which browser to open it in:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gd43NYBzHuk
```

Comment: Can you give an example XML layout? Or at least the part that is relevant to this question. Also be sure to include relevant string resources.

Comment: I added some information. If you need any more, let me know. Thank you!

Comment: How do you set the text displayed in the `TextView`?

Comment: textSummary.setText(Html.fromHtml(object.getDescription()));

Comment: The API is parsed into an object. The getDescription pulls the description portion out of that object.

Comment: "The API is parsed into an object." I'm trying to make sense of this sentence. Do you mean that you are calling a REST API and parsing the **response**? If so, you probably need slightly more sophisticated logic for setting the text of the `TextView` to ensure that it contains the full URL. Perhaps you can prepend the domain name?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Sorry for being vague. The description portion of my custom object is a String. So, I suppose the way to do this would be to work some logic up that will find partial links and complete them? I was hoping there would be an easier way. I think setting intent filters, actions, and data would work if every link inside of that description was partial. However, there are full ones as well. This may not be worth the effort.

Comment: How is the app supposed to know the root part of the link? In a web page, the browser has the address of the current page and can use that to complete any relative paths. The browser will concatenate the path of the current page with a relative path in a link in order to send the request to the correct server. It sounds like you need to duplicate this kind of logic.

Comment: Yes, that is the information that I am looking for. However, I don't know where to even start with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

> android:autoLink="web"

```
    <TextView android:id="@+id/detail_summary"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="3dp"
    android:paddingEnd="3dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

this **TextView** don't need onClickLinstner

Comment: This works better than what I was previously looking for! Originally, I was looking for a way to implement every single link that was inside of my summaries. However, this just removes any that aren't complete and only leaves the ones that aren't! Thank you! I would upvote this answer, but I lack the 15 reputation. (I'm a new developer)